# How to test the dynamic color of a Widget using testWidgets

Tags: testing, flutter, widget, themes

I want to write unit tests for a custom widget, specifically check the color of a nested `Text` widget that is themed based on `BuildContext`. How do I test for different styles based on the `BuildContext`?

The widget to test:

```dart
class ThemedText extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextStyle inheritedTextStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle;
    Color customColor = inheritedTextStyle.color;
    if (inheritedTextStyle.color == Colors.blue) {
      customColor = Colors.red;
    }

    return Text(
      'Themed',
      style: inheritedTextStyle.copyWith(color: customColor),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to write two tests:

- Supply an inherited `TextStyle` with a color that is `Colors.blue`, and test whether the `Text` widget is rendered with the overriden color (i.e. `Colors.blue`).
- Supply an inherited `TextStyle` with a color that is NOT `Colors.blue` (e.g. `Colors.green`), and test whether the `Text` widget is rendered with the inherited color (e.g. `Colors.green`).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works for me:

```
final textColorFinder = tester.widget<Text>(find.byType(Text));

expect(textColorFinder.style.color, Colors.red);
```